# Publisher and Editor only without publishing rights role possible?

Tags: users, nodes

I want to have 2 user roles in the site:
one that can create content but not being able to publish
and the other just a supervisor that can (aprove-publish)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a workflow, for example "Draft", "Requires Review" and "Published". The Editor can only take content to "requires review" while the publisher has permissions to change the workflow state to Published which is then visible to all users on the site.

http://drupal.org/project/workflow

If you want to get really fancy you could use Rules to automatically email the publisher when content goes into "requires review" so the Publisher gets a notification. or you could setup a view for them...